# Help with JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if a string starts with the following: "+="

I've tried

```
str.search("+="));
```

and

```
str.search("\+\="));
```

but get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular
>   expression: /+=/: Nothing to repeat

Can you help me with this, and also recommend a good resource for JavaScript regular expressions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^\+=/.test(str);
```

It will return `true` if the string starts with `+=`. The `^` (caret) says "match from the beginning of the string". The `+` needs to be escaped because it is a regex metacharacter that means "one or more of the preceding" (and that's not what we want).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex to test against a fixed substring. Just do this:

```
str.indexOf("+=")===0
```

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting is becaue `+` has special meaning in a regex. It mean "the previous pattern is prepeated 1 or more times". Therefore, to search for a literal `+` you need to escape the character using a backslash.

Also, to check its at the beginning of the string, start your regex with a `^`

Therefore, the pattern you want is `^\+=`

Answer (score 3):

One option (among other) would be:

```
if(str.substr(0,2) == "+=")
```

And I think it would be the fastest if dealing with large strings.